# Flip rows in a Matrix(2D) list in Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, reverse

I have a 2D list called tab:

```
[[1, 2, 3],   # <---  first row
[4, 5, 6],    # <---  2nd row
[7, 8, 9]]    # <---- last row
```

with tab[lines][columns]. For instance, `tab[0][1] = 2`. I want to reverse the order of each column to get the output format:

```
7 8 9   # <---- become first row
4 5 6   # <===== 2nd row. no change
1 2 3   # <----- become last row
```

Comment: It seems that  you mean to reverse *rows* of this matrix - list of list. Not column,

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `[::-1]` operator as if it were a string:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]

l = l[::-1]
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
[[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `reverse()` to reverse the order in a list. In your case, this would mean doing the following:

```
>>> tab.reverse()
>>> tab
[[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

If you wanted to reverse the order on the minor index of your 2D array, you could combine this with `map`, like so:

```
>>> list(map(lambda c: c.reverse(), tab))
>>> tab
[[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]
```